# I can't access variable model in javascript when i use "ng-list"

Tags: javascript, angularjs

HTML

```
<input type="text" ng-list ng-model="OtherHobby" />{{OtherHobby}} <br />
    {{AllHobbys}}
```

Javascript

```
$scope.OtherHobby = [];
        $scope.AllHobbys = $scope.OtherHobby;
```

I test this code. "OtherHobby" is OK,It show what i expect when you type something in textbox. But "AllHobbys" does not. It doesn't show anything. Why is that?

Comment: Add **complete** code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue may come from references. You can fix that by initializing "otherHobby" as an object.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" ng-list ng-model="otherHobby.value" />{{otherHobby.value}} </br> {{allHobbys.value}}
```

Javascript:

```
$scope.otherHobby = {};
$scope.allHobbys = $scope.otherHobby;
```

By the way, you should use camelCase for variables.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. i follow your code and it's OK but i don't understand. Why is that? As i know, JSON and Array are objects. they should be the same behavior.

Comment: I guess you mean Array is also Object in JavaScript (JSON is a data format). I suppose the initial value of "otherHobby" when you declare it as an array might have been changed, so "allHobbys" and "otherHobby" don't refer to the same array anymore. A quick fix is to declare them as an object whose value may point to different arrays, but the value property's address won't change.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$watch` on your var. This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ubcp26a5/) should help ya.

=)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `$watch` but try to avoid that if you can, because angular has to maintain a deep clone of the entire array to watch it.

I don't see why you need to have 2 references to the exact same object. If you can clarify that maybe I can suggest a better approach. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Few points to note

1. `$scope.OtherHobby = [];` // you are creating an array which no longer will hold array values. As you assigned ng-model = OtherHobby. It will hold the string values which you type in textbox.
2. When you say `$scope.allHobbys = $scope.otherHobby;` // this will make $scope.allHobbys point to same memory location as that of $scope.otherHobby;
3. But when you update value in textbox. It created a new string (As strings are immutable on the universe)
4. So `$scope.OtherHobby` now point to some other location
5. But your `$scope.allHobby` points to same old location

Take a look at,

## [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Dipak1991/3vju44r4/1/)